# Django app on Azure not getting static files

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, django-staticfiles

Got  my Django project on a Azure webapp, but when I call on SSH terminal:

> Python manage.py collectstatic

It says 252 files copied but my static files are not visible on my templates and static folder in wwwroot its empty...Here's my wwwroot structure:

```
wwwroot
|---Myproject
|---manage.py
|---oryx-manifest.toml
|---hostingstart.html
|---static //With all my static files
├── myapp
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
|   |   |---Images
|   |   |   |--myimage.png
|   |   |   |--myimage2.png
│   └── templates
```

And this is my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   ('myapp', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'static')),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Any idea why or what am I doing wrong ?, does Azure collect different ?

EDIT> When I go to my website my images don´t show...Im calling them like this on template:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'Images/myimage.png' %}" /><br>
```

EDIT 2 /////

In wwwroot creates indeed a folder with all my statics, but when I load my template they don´t show, in wen console I get this error for myimage.png and myimage2.png :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Is that you cannot find the folder called **staticfiles** at the root level (same directory as myapp/)? Not sure about this line "my static files are not visible on my templates". Could you please post the folder structure in wwwroot?

Comment: @DorisLv Thanks for reply, of course, I´ve updated my question to add wwwroot folder structure, now it says 252 files copied but static folder still empty and my images are not showing on my website.

Comment: @jsanchezs How are you deploying your app to Azure?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara I used the deployment center on Azure´s portal.

Comment: @jsanchezs Have you tried to copy them over manually and check? Or with a different deployment method?

Comment: @jsanchezs Any update with the above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it !!

Just had to add this:  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) to url patterns like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
        path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And it did the trick, hope it helps to anyone else!!

Comment: Don't forget to import settings: `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: Do you know why this wasn't required locally but is required on Azure?

Answer (score 9):

Django does not serve static files in production mode.

The only time it serves static files is when you turn DEBUG = True which is in development mode and this is not recommended in a production setting.

Django recommends to serve static files via CND or any other webserver. However if your website is minimal and does not get high volume traffic you can serve your static files using Django whitenoise and here is how you do it.

The below solution works on python 3.7 and Django 3.2

**Step 1: Install whitenoise package**

```
pip install whitenoise
```

**Step 2: Ensure your BASE_DIR looks like the below**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

**Step 3: Add these to your settings.py. If you get any errors try commenting out STATICFILES_STORAGE and check**

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

**Step 4: WhiteNoise middleware should be placed directly after the Django SecurityMiddleware (if you are using it) and before all other middleware**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

**Step 5: Ensure this is how you reference static files in your templates(also check if you have `{% load static %}` mentioned in your template**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'appname/styles.css' %}">
```

**Step 6: Run collect static**

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**Step 7: Turn DEBUG = False and run the server to verify it works.**

Some additional resources to read further:

[whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html)
[Django on Azure - beyond "hello world"](https://tonybaloney.github.io/posts/django-on-azure-beyond-hello-world.html)

Answer (score 1):

Few points to note:

Below line will change

```
STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Myproject/static_files/'))
```

to

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

> **You are using pointing to completely different folder here. Hence always empty You need the collectstatic command to copy files to
> Project > static directory**

---

Below remove the line *`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`*...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), #Not Required since you already mentioned it in STATIC_URL
('myapp', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'static')),
)
```

### Reason:

- **`STATIC_ROOT`** is the folder where static files will be stored after
  using manage.py collectstatic

> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect
> static files for deployment.
>
> If the staticfiles contrib app is enabled (default) the collectstatic management command will collect static files into this
> directory. See the howto on managing static files for more details
> about usage.

- **`STATICFILES_DIRS`** is the list of folders where Django will search for
  additional static files aside from the static folder of each app
  installed.

> This setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will
> traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled, e.g. if you use
> the collectstatic or findstatic management command or use the static
> file serving view.

***If issue still persists check your static file directory in apache mod_wsgi config file in the server if it is configured properly.***

Check this link for help on that >> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

---

**Cheers!!!**

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Did what you told me but still don´t get statics, I mean, in wwwroot collectstatics indeed creates a folder with everything, but when I load my page they don´t show and in web console shows : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)...

Comment: Could you share your deployment configurations for your django app in Azure? How & where have you pointed your static folder in your config?

Comment: Great. Good luck mate! :)

Comment: @jsanchezs This only works if you turn on debugging mode and stops working as soon as you turn off debugging which can't be used for production. Did it get it to work while DEBUG = False?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out Whitenoise for serving your static files with Django. I haven't had an issue serving them since integrating Whitenoise. Try swapping it out with your current static file finders setup.

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html