# No CSS in Admin panel in Azure App Service hosted Django APP

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I cant figure out how to make Azure App Service use css for admin panel.
In settings.py I included these:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

   
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

But somehow css is still not working for the admin panel.
How can I fix this? As far as I know Oryx which works under Azure App Service should automatically run

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'licenses_api',
]
```

Comment: make sure that you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in installed_apps, is this an apache server?

Comment: @Sumithran I have it. Im not sure if this is Apache server, its basic azure app service app.

Comment: Hi @AlexT, how are things going? I noticed that `@DorisLv` has shared some suggestions in the answer. Please have a check with it. If it helpful to you, you can mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are something to check might help:

1. Click F12 on your Admin page to check if it is the `404 Not Found` error.
2. Check the static files exist in your azure web app or not. You could see it in `https://{your-web-app}.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/` site.
3. Check if your file structure match with the `settings.py`. Any spell error would make the static file not found.
4. If your file exists well, you should check if you use them correctly in your code like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817361/13586071). Here is how he use:

   ```
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
            path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try to add these code lines to
[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5zHv.png)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Then import these lines to the
[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLum.png)

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
```

Finaly you have to add these lines to urlpatterns in
[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLum.png)

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

(If you have not already created a *static* file please make sure to create one before you try this)
It's worked severl times for me and hope this will work for you too