# Django REST API on Azure Web App - Static Files

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a basic django app with django rest framework.  I have deployed it to Azure Web App and it working fine except the I am not able to serve the static files.  I have the following in `setting.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/site/wwwroot/static/"  # Azure path
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The application is looking for `www.domain.com/static/"`.  I did ran `python manage.py collectstatic` file on azure and it does create a directory will all the file at the above location.

Not sure what's wrong, may be something to do with how azure containiser the application.  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817361/7077417 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#serve-static-files-for-django-apps

Comment: thanks.  Adding the Url in the url.py did the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [dan webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7077417/dan-webb). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

Add the `URL` in `url.py` as per below code

```
**from django.conf import settings**

**from django.conf.urls.static import static**

**urlpatterns = [**

**path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),**

**path('admin/', admin.site.urls),**

**] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)**
```